# Javascript implementation of UAX 29 Unicode Text Segmentation?

Tags: javascript, unicode, text-segmentation

Is anyone aware of any JavaScript implementations of [UAX #29, Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/)? I'm specifically interested in [Word Boundaries](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries).

I was hopeful when I came across [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com), but it seems to use the standard JavaScript implementation of `\b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter is a pure js implementation of [UAX #29 Grapheme Cluster Boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries).

There is also an ES proposal on implementing Intl.Segmenter using UAX #29, see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-word-boundaries is one, but it requires Node for some unix native unicode libs; it's not pure js.